# Billionaire wants to leave behind a legacy iconic structure to be remembered

Tags: science-based

Imagine you are a billionaire today and you want to leave behind some kind of monument/structure as a long term legacy. Something to flatter your ego and ensure you are remembered on a regular basis into the future. The statue of liberty, Eiffel tower, Sydney opera house and pyramids are good examples of lasting iconic structures.

Obviously the billionaire does not want to copy something already extant but wants their own unique structure. They have 30 billion to spend with another 3 billion put into trust for its upkeep in the longer term. It must last at least several hundred years and a few thousand would be even better.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd imagine it would depend on how said billionaire got their riches. If it were, say, Daddy's Inheritance, then it might be something like a statue of themselves.

Comment: This seems to violate our idea-generation policy. I didn't realize this until I answered. Whoops. :( See: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/522/whats-wrong-with-idea-generation-questions

Comment: @PipperChip You are correct, and the fact that your answer is a list of possibilities is good evidence for that. This question needs to be made more constrained, or at the very least a way to rate one answer over others needs to be added.

Comment: At its core there is a good question here, but it needs more guidance both in terms of what sort of structure is wanted and how the "best" would be chosen.

Comment: Genetically-engineered STD named after himself?

Answer (score 2):

## Buy a Small Nation, Make It Your Own!

Buy a small city or nation (despite no one I know of selling one), turn it into someplace great. You could try a poor country like [Haiti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiti), whose GDP is somewhere between 2/3 and 1/2 your spending money. You get a "founding father myth" and many grateful individuals. It's a pretty sweet way to go. Plus, your face on the money's currency!

## Carve Yourself Into A Mountain!

You, or rather your image, will be in stone, so it will last a while if you choose the right place and stone. It could become your tomb, but then you're simply a mashup of Ancient Egyptians and [Gutzon Borglum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutzon_Borglum). You can even make it a tourist attraction, which can help fund its maintenance in perpetuity. You will be remembered, even if the civilization dies and elephants rise up to perform archeology on former human structures.

## Build the First Commercial Spaceport!

This may need to wait until [SpaceX](http://www.spacex.com/) and other companies are making regular flights, but you can make the first dedicated commercial spaceport. You can get revenue from people renting out rooms, and sustain it that way. It's not exactly a dedicated monolithic monument, and it may fail after you die, but this gamble could pay off.

## First Statue On the Moon

The cost of launching a space shuttle is about [1.5 billion USD](http://usgovinfo.about.com/od/space/ss/Cost-Of-Space-Shuttle-Launch.htm). The cost per kg of sending things to low earth orbit is measured in [thousands of US dollars](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1989/what-is-the-current-cost-per-pound-to-send-something-into-leo). That leaves you with more money than you know what to deal with, so you can put that on your monument. Make a super-durable statue of yourself, like made of tungsten carbide, launch it to the moon, plant it somewhere, like the bottom of a crater, so it lasts a until something substantial hits it. This could be [billions of years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_craters)! Better yet, make this super durable statue contain your remains, so you are incased in a version of yourself, preserved on the moon! If you make yourself shiny or large enough, people from earth can see you when they look up (with a telescope). *How's that for memorable?*

Comment: Having money equivalent to the GDP of a country (or city) doesn't let you "buy" it, though it could give you considerable influence over the government. However, making radical changes to a country's distribution of wealth is a complex political and socio-economic problem that could take decades, perhaps longer than this aging billionaire can wait. Of course, you could use your money to  build your own Utopian city from the ground up, though there's no guarantee that it will outlive you, after you pass on, the caretakers of the city may not share your vision